# Error while creating file with special character

Tags: r, file, special-characters

I am writing to a file with special character.

```
fname<- "1,2-dioleoyl-GPC (18:1/18:1)*[media]"
cat(1,file=fname)
```

but I get following error:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
>     cannot open file '1,2-dioleoyl-GPC (18:1/18:1)*[media]': No such file or directory

How can I avoid such an error?

Comment: You expect the filename to be `1,2-dioleoyl-GPC (18:1/18:1)*[media]`?

Comment: Yes, it should be like this only.

Comment: But you do realize that a filename cannot contain `*`, `:`, `/` characters?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/711269

Comment: is there any way to manipulate filename as this is not generated by me they are already in system.

Comment: There is no way such filename exists on the filesystem. Where are you getting these names from  / what system produces them?